# Startup iTunes to Shared Library / Home Sharing

Tags: macos, itunes

I've enabled iTunes Home Sharing on 2 Macs, and I want the remote iTunes to start up directly to the shared library instead of the default local library and manually selecting "Shared Library".

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this. THere might be a way to script it, but I doubt that; I don't think Apple wants people to be able to do this.